# How would you set up a URL rewrite rule to handle 404s in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, url-rewrite, 404

I want to write a rewrite rule that is only activated if the url is a 404. Does anyone know how I would go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 404 page redirection rules:

- If Magento admin set A Cms page as 404 page.then it hit
  `Mage_Cms_IndexController` at `noRouteAction()`.
- Else,if redirect to `Mage_Cms_IndexController` at
  `defaultNoRouteAction()`